# Requested method POST not supported, Spring MVC JDBCTemplate

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

Getting 405 Error: Request method `'POST'` not supported in Spring MVC JDBCTemplate CRUD operation.

> How do I resolve 405 'POST' method not supported in the piece of code
>   using Spring MVC and JDBCTemplate for crud operation?

URL accessing the DELETE statement: `/JdbcTemplate/user/delete/9`
Here's the method that in the controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap model) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(USER_EDIT_PAGE);
        User user = userService.getUserById(id); 
//      User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        return mav;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        userService.updateUser(user);
        return "redirect:/user/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@PathVariable ("id") Integer id) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(USER_LIST_VIEW);

        userService.deleteUser(id);

        String message = "Team was successfully deleted.";
        mav.addObject("message", message);

        return mav;
    }
```

Now not sure about the JSP that is being called when the URL is passed:
list.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/taglibs.jsp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/views/includes/meta.jsp" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>User List</h2>
        <table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Zip</td>
                <td>Country</td>
                <!-- <td>Edit</td> -->
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${user.id}</td>
                        <td><%-- <a href="/user/edit/${user.id}"> --%>${user.lastName},${user.firstName}<!-- </a> --></td>
                        <td>${user.city}</td>
                        <td>${user.zip}</td>
                        <td>${user.country}</td>
                        <td><form:form
                                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/delete/${user.id}"
                                method="POST">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                    value="Delete" />
                            </form:form></td>
                        <%-- <td><a href="edit/${user.id}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="delete?id=${user.id}">Delete</a></td> --%>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <td colspan="7"><a href="register">Add New User</a></td>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

edit.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/taglibs.jsp" %>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <c:import url="/WEB-INF/views/includes/meta.jsp" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

    <c:if test="${empty user}">
        <h3>User not found: ${id}</h3>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty user}">
        <h1>Edit User</h1>
        <form:form method="POST" action="update" commandName="user">
            <form:hidden path="id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="firstName">First Name:</form:label>
                <form:input path="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="lastName">Last Name:</form:label>
                <form:input path="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="city">City:</form:label>
                <form:input path="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="zip">Zip:</form:label>
                <form:input path="zip" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form:label path="country">Country:</form:label>
                <form:input path="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Country"/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </form:form>
    </c:if>

    <br><a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The controller only recognizes GETs to /delete/{id}:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteUser(@PathVariable ("id") Integer id) {
```

On list.jsp you have a form that sends a POST to /delete/{id}, so that seems to be the problem:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/delete/${user.id}" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Delete" />
</form:form>
```

Change the method on the form from POST to GET and that should resolve your problem. If you want to allow GETs and POSTs to /delete/{id}, removing `method = RequestMethod.GET` from the `@RequestMapping` on deleteUser will allow it to handle all HTTP methods and not just GET.

Comment: There is no action or the request sent will not delete the records from the table when I remove `method = RequestMethod.GET` from `/delete/{id}` in deleteUser() method.